# Apparently inconsistent behavior when copying numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-copy

Consider the following minimal example. Can somebody explain the apparently inconsistent logic of `numpy` when it comes to copying list elements of varying nesting depths?

```
import numpy as np

L = [[[[1, 1], 2, 3]]]
A1 = np.array(L)

A2 = A1.copy()

A1[0][0][2] = 'xx'
A1[0][0][0][0] = 'yy'

print "\nA1 after changes:\n{}".format(A1)
print "\nA2 only partially changed:\n{}".format(A2)
```

Results:

```
A1 after changes:
[[[['yy', 1] 2 'xx']]]

A2 only partially changed:
[[[['yy', 1] 2 3]]]
```

Then:

```
>>> print A1[0][0][2] == A2[0][0][2]
False
>>> print A1[0][0][0][0] == A2[0][0][0][0]
True
```

I have a hard time explaining to myself why `3` is not replaced, but `1` in a deeper level is.

1. `A2 = np.array(A, copy=True)` and `A2 = np.empty_like(A); np.copyto(A4, A)` behave the same as the code above
2. `A2 = A[:]` behaves the same as `A2 = A`: both are identical after changes
3. `import copy; A2 = copy.deepcopy(A)` is the only solution I found to create an independent copy.

Comment: Given that you've figured out that only a deep copy stops this from happening, what's confusing you? In the other cases, you're copying *references to the same mutable object*.

Comment: It's because you have an array with `dtype=object` ... Basically, you've got an array that holds a reference to a python list and 2 python integers.  If you copy the array, it just copies the references.

Comment: I don't like the duplicate.  Numpy arrays have special copy issues.  And `dtype` object arrays further complicate the issue.  This question should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your array, and understand its structure first:

```
In [139]: A1
Out[139]: array([[[[1, 1], 2, 3]]], dtype=object)

In [140]: A1.shape
Out[140]: (1, 1, 3)
```

It's a `dtype=object` array; that is the elements are object pointers, not numbers.  Also it is 3d, with 3 elements.

```
In [142]: A1[0,0]  
Out[142]: array([[1, 1], 2, 3], dtype=object)
```

Since it is an array, `A1[0,0]` is better than `A1[0][0]`.  Functionally the same, but clearer.  `A1[0,0,:]` is even better.  Anyways, at this level we still have an array with shape `(3,)`, i.e. 1d with 3 elements.

```
In [143]: A1[0,0,0]
Out[143]: [1, 1]

In [144]: A1[0,0,2]
Out[144]: 3
```

Now we get a list and numbers, the individual elements of `A1`.  The list is mutable, the number is not.

We can change the 3rd element (a number) to a string:

```
In [148]: A1[0,0,2]='xy'
```

To change an element of the 1st element, a list, I have to use the mixed indexing, not a 4 level array indexing.

```
In [149]: A1[0,0,0,0]
...
IndexError: too many indices for array

In [150]: A1[0,0,0][0]='yy'

In [151]: A1
Out[151]: array([[[['yy', 1], 2, 'xy']]], dtype=object)
```

`A1` is still a 3d object array; we have just change a couple of elements.  The 'xy' change is different from the 'yy' change.  One changed the array, the other a list element of the array.

`A2=A1.copy()` makes a new array with copies of the elements (the data buffer) of `A1`.  So `A2` has pointers to the same objects as `A1`.

The 'xy' changed the pointer in `A1`, but did not change the `A2` copy.

The 'yy' change modified the list pointed to by `A1`. `A2` has a pointer to the same list, so it sees the change.

Note that `L`, the original nested list sees the same change:

```
In [152]: L
Out[152]: [[[['yy', 1], 2, 3]]]
```

`A3 = A[:]` produces a `view` of `A1`.  `A3` has the same data buffer as `A1`, so it sees all the changes.

`A4 = A` would also see the same changes, but `A4` is a new reference to `A1`, not a view or a copy.

The `duplicate answer` that was raised earlier dealt with references, copies and deep copies of lists.  That is relevant here because `L` is a list, and `A1` is an object array, which in many ways is an array wrapper around a list.  But `A1` is also numpy array, which has the added distinction between `view` and `copy`.

This is not a good use of `numpy` arrays, not even the object dtype version.  It's an instructive example, but too confusing to be practical.  If you need to do a `deepcopy` on an array, you probably are using arrays wrong.